# python: type error and index error (2.7.6)

Tags: python, list, indexing, typeerror

I am fairly new to python and I am having a problem on 2.7.6 that is not a problem on 3.4.4

The code:

```
def answer(population, x, y, strength):

# make sure Z is infectable
if population[x][y] > strength:
    return population
else:
    population[x][y] = -1

# get array dimentions
rows = len(population)
cols = len(population[0])

# declare checking array
toCheck = []
toCheck.append([x,y])

# loop 4 way check
while(1):
    #store and pop current element
    i = toCheck[0][0]
    j = toCheck[0][1]
    toCheck.pop(0)

    # left
    if j != 0:
        if population[i][j-1] <= strength and population[i][j-1] != -1:
            population[i][j-1] = -1
            toCheck.append([i,j-1])

    # top
    if i != 0:
        if population[i-1][j] < strength and population[i-1][j] != -1:
            population[i-1][j] = -1
            toCheck.append([i-1,j])

    # right 
    if j != cols-1:
        if population[i][j+1] > strength and population[i][j+1] != -1:
            population[i][j+1] = -1
            toCheck.append([i,j+1])

    # bottom
    if i != rows-1:
        if population[i+1][j] > strength and population[i+1][j] != -1:
            population[i+1][j] = -1
            toCheck.append([i+1][j])

    if len(toCheck) == 0:
        return population
```

gives me a 'TypeError'. While the code:

```
def answer(population, x, y, strength):

# make sure Z is infectable
if population[x][y] > strength:
    return population
else:
    population[x][y] = -1

# get array dimentions
rows = len(population)
cols = len(population[0])

# declare checking array
toCheck = [[]]
toCheck.append([x,y])

# loop 4 way check
while(1):
    #store and pop current element
    i = toCheck[0][0]
    j = toCheck[0][1]
    toCheck.pop(0)

    # left
    if j != 0:
        if population[i][j-1] <= strength and population[i][j-1] != -1:
            population[i][j-1] = -1
            toCheck.append([i,j-1])

    # top
    if i != 0:
        if population[i-1][j] < strength and population[i-1][j] != -1:
            population[i-1][j] = -1
            toCheck.append([i-1,j])

    # right 
    if j != cols-1:
        if population[i][j+1] > strength and population[i][j+1] != -1:
            population[i][j+1] = -1
            toCheck.append([i,j+1])

    # bottom
    if i != rows-1:
        if population[i+1][j] > strength and population[i+1][j] != -1:
            population[i+1][j] = -1
            toCheck.append([i+1][j])

    if len(toCheck) == 0:
        return population
```

Gives me and 'IndexError'. Both of these errors occur at the line i=toCheck[0][0].
Please help! thank you.

Comment: format the code indentation correctly

Comment: In your code, `funk` is never called and no value for `population` is ever provided.  Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your question appropriately.

Comment: What are you expecting that state of `toCheck` to be after `toCheck.append([x, y])`?

Comment: It is supposed to be a two dim list with [x,y] being the first element.

Comment: this function is being called by another program so it is not supposed to be called here. Sorry about the verify problem.

Comment: I have added the whole code block now

Comment: Please do not deface your posts.

Comment: Could you create a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? For instance, you could add the parameters you're using to test your functions

Answer (score 0):

Edit: this response was for an older version of the question's code.

Assuming that all of your code is supposed to be within funk():

You need to terminate your while loop once toCheck is empty. The original version tries to index an empty list after you've popped off all of the values. Try this:

```
# loop 4 way check
while len(toCheck) > 0:
    #store and pop current element
    i = toCheck[0][0]
    j = toCheck[0][1]
    toCheck.pop(0)
```

Also, you don't need to declare toCheck before adding values. You can replace

```
toCheck = [[],[]]
toCheck.append([x,y])
```

With

```
toCheck = [x, y]
```